# Undefined is not a function error d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to load my own data into this d3.js visualization but I keep getting the error `Undefined is not a function`. The only difference is that, instead of defining `freqData` as they did, I defined mine to load from a data file

```
var freqData = d3.json("//sjs72/Users/ksdf/file.json", function(fdata) {
  console.log(fdata[0]);
});
```

It happens at the line

```
fData.forEach(function(d){d.total=d.freq.low+d.freq.mid+d.freq.high;});
```

Could anyone help me understand where I'm going wrong?

EDIT: The call I make is dashboard('#dashboard',freqData); The function dashboard takes the argument fData, which in this case I'm loading freqData into

Update:

I changed my variable definition and the resulting code looks like

```
var freqData;
  function doSomethingWithData() {
  console.log(freqData);
}

d3.json("//sjs72/Users/ksdf/file.json", function(dataFromServer)    {
  freqData = dataFromServer;
  doSomethingWithData();
}

dashboard('#dashboard',freqData);
```

But now I'm just getting the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

On the last line of my script

Comment: Is that line you're saying the error occurs at inside the function within `freqData`? According to the error, `fData` is undefined. Put a breakpoint in and see what's going  on.

Comment: Is it because you assign the data to `freqData` and then attempt to reference `fData`?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong: `d3.json()` is an asynchronous function, which does not return a value. See [*"Returning array from d3.json()"*](/q/12656580).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis for your `d3.json()` call. That may very well be producing the issue for you. Corrected code:

```
var freqData;
  function doSomethingWithData() {
  console.log(freqData);
}

d3.json("//sjs72/Users/ksdf/file.json", function(dataFromServer)    {
    freqData = dataFromServer;
    doSomethingWithData();
  }
); // Added this here
dashboard('#dashboard',freqData);
```